# Locally constant sheaf which is not a cover

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, sheaf-theory

Let $F$ be a locally constant sheaf on a topological space $X$ trivialized by an open cover $\bigcup_iU_i$ with $F\vert_{U_i}\cong\Delta S_i$, where the $S_i$ are sets and $\Delta$ refers to the constant sheaf functor. Denoting $U_i\cap U_j$ by $U_{ij}$ we therefore have isomorphisms $\Delta S_i\vert_{U_{ij}}\cong F\vert_{U_{ij}}\cong\Delta S_j\vert_{U_{ij}}$. In particular for all $p\in U_{ij}$ we have an isomorphism of stalks $\left(\Delta S_i\vert_{U_{ij}}\right)_p\cong\left(\Delta S_j\vert_{U_{ij}}\right)_p$, so when $U_{ij}\neq\varnothing$ one finds an isomorphism $\theta_{ij}(p):S_i\to S_j$ since the stalks of a constant sheaf on an object are just that object.

In a section 1.1 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.1771.pdf), a *covering of $X$ split by $\bigcup_iU_i$* is a locally constant sheaf trivialized by the $U_i$ such that whenever $U_{ij}\neq\varnothing$, $\theta_{ij}(p)=\theta_{ij}(q)$ for all $p,q\in U_{ij}$. In other words, the transition maps on the stalks are the same at any point.

I'm struggling to see what this condition is telling us, and why it is always true for locally connected $X$.

- What is an example of a locally constant sheaf on, say, $\mathbb{Q}$, which does not satisfy this condition?
- Why is this condition always satisfied when the space is locally connected?

I am studying this in the context of fundamental groups/groupoids/progroupoids/localic progroupoids of (Grothendieck) topoi as the paper indicates, and I'm currently trying to clarify the role of local connectedness.

Something interesting about the theory of fundamental group-like structures is that for a connected topological space (and possibly for more general connected topoi? e.g. the étale topos of a connected scheme) is that the local connectedness requirement does not appear when classifying finite covers. For example, for *any* connected topological space $X$, the category of finite covers is a Galois category. So I'm curious to know if maybe there is some result which says if the sheaf is locally constant then it is a cover.

Comment: @ronno It doesn't imply that, as far as I can tell. Just to be clear, because the notation is confusing: in the question $\theta_{ij}$ doesn't mean anything, though I guess we could let that be the name of the isomorphism *of sheaves* $\Delta S_i\vert_{U_{ij}}\to\Delta S_j\vert_{U_{ij}}$. The induced map of stalks  over the point $p$ (which is an isomorphism of sets) is $\theta_{ij}(p)$ - $p$ is not an input to a function $\theta_{ij}$ which is an isomorphism. More consistent notation would maybe have been $(\theta_{ij})_p$.

Comment: Nvm I missed the $(p)$ in "an isomorphism $\theta_{ij}(p)$ ..."

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, so a comment, not an answer. Note that $\theta_{ij}(p)$ depend on the choices of isomorphisms $F|_{U_i} \cong \Delta S_i$. If $U_i$ is connected then such an isomorphism is determined by the identification (choice of isomorphism) $F_p \cong S_i$ (and then, also assuming $U_j$ is connected, $\theta_{ij}(p)$ is given by $S_i \cong F_p \cong S_j$). You can probably cook up an example by taking a split trivialization and then twisting the isomorphism on one $U_i$ by some non-constant but locally constant map $U_i \to \operatorname{Aut}(S)$.